# DotNetNuke DDRMenu Couldn't load menu style 'MenuProfile': Illegal characters

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, ddrmenu

I've added a new menu to our skin that loads a different menu style and shows only a special submenu.

```
<dnn:MENU ID="MenuProfile" MenuStyle="MenuProfile" IncludeHidden="true" runat="server" ></dnn:MENU>
```

This loads from the directory

DNN-INSTALL/Portals/_default/Skin/mySkin/MenuProfile/

The menu loads just fine in my development environment. Now I've packaged the skin and deployed it with installing it in Host/Extensions and the files are deployed on the server. I've checked that every file is in the right path on the server. But it runs into the following exception:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>    Couldn't load menu style 'MenuProfile': System.ArgumentException: Illegal character in path.
>      at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
>      ...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the skin is really in the same relative directory structure as in your development environment.

Also check in the menudef.xml file that paths are correct.

Can you load a different menu style successfully?

Comment: in my packaging prozess the menudef.xml got lost for the menu. Fixed that and now it works. Thank you